# Como eu removo o sublinhado do texto de um link?

Tags: css, html5, text, style

Eu sei que essa pergunta já foi feita aqui mas mesmo utilizando o text-decoration: none; o sublinhado continua, no maximo o text-decoration: none; remove a cor do texto que estou utilizando.

O código  CSS que estou usando para o texto desse menu é este aqui:

```
 span {color:black; font-size: 30px; font-family: 'Merriweather',
 serif; font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive; border-radius: 10px;} span
 {background-color:bisque; transition: color 10s;} span:hover
 {background-color: beige;}
span {text-decoration: none;}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o elemento que possui o sublinhado é a âncora (`<a>`), você deve aplicar o estilo nela. Aplicar o estilo no `<span>` não causará efeito, pois você estará removendo o `text-decoration` de algo que já está sem `text-decoration`.

Veja o exemplo do CSS em questão aplicado em ambas tags:

```css
.semSublinhado {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<span class='semSublinhado'><a href='#'>Link com sublinhado</a></span>

<span><a href='#' class='semSublinhado'>Link sem sublinhado</a></span>
```